# How to enable a system-wide function for users including sudo?

Tags: bash, alias

I want to make a global alias for `killprocessatport` so I put at the end in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
fuserfunction() {
    fuser -KILL -k -n tcp $1
}
alias killprocessatport=fuserfunction
```

Then i put in `/etc/profile` at the very end

`source /etc/bash.bashrc`

And then I load it with `bash /etc/profile`expecting the alias with parameter to work but it doesn't:

```
$ killprocessatport 80
killprocessatport: command not found
```

Why not?

Comment: did you log out and in again, or at least source /etc/profile or other in your shell?

Comment: also, just call your function killprocessatport, there is no need to define an alias for a function, you can call a function directly from the command line

Comment: Try placing this code in it's own file (fuserfunc.sh) in /etc/profile.d then exit and exec a new shell as wich suggested and it should work.

Comment: Thanks but it wdoesn't work when I `sudo` it. I put the code in `etc/profile.d/fuserfunc.sh` (the 4 lines that also define the alias) and I can use it as any user except when I call itwith sudo, which I must for ports below 1024. What can be done to enable it getting called with sudo?

Comment: Why would you make this an alias at all, rather than just having the user run `fuserfunction` directly, or just naming the function `killprocessatport`?

Comment: Anyhow, `bash /etc/profile` runs /etc/profile in a new shell and then exits, so of course it won't have the desired effect of modifying your existing shell; that's what `source /etc/profile` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias *or* a function in this case. Create an executable script in a location that's on your PATH (as configured by sudo, if your `/etc/suoders` modifies root's PATH).

```
#!/bin/sh
exec fuser -KILL -k -n tcp "$@"
```

Save the script, then set its permissions with `chmod +x`.

Comment: Thanks! I put the code in a file `killatport.sh` that I can execute with `bash ./killatport 8088` for example. Is there a default place to put it for example `/bin/ ` or some directory that already exists? If I put it in `/usr/bin/` then it seems it wworkks for all users including root when I do sudo. Thank you! I hope it was done the right way.

Comment: @909Niklas, FYI, using `.sh` extensions is not a best practice. If you want the script to be called `killatport`, just name the file that -- and if you set up the permissions and the first line correctly, you won't need to use `bash` when running it. `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` typically *do* already exist, and are the conventional place for commands that aren't installed through your operating system's package management infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

it does not work because when you do:

```
bash /etc/profile
```

you open a new shell, execute the profile script, and get back to your current shell.

Actually, that's why to load the content of `/etc/bash.bashrc` you do `source /etc/bash.bashrc` in the `/etc/profile`.

Thus to load it in your current shell, you should run:

```
source /etc/profile
```

instead.

*Nota Bene*:

1. It's though a better idea to add your own aliases in `~/.bashrc` which gets automatically sourced by bash on load ;
2. If you really want it to be global, follow @user1257931's suggestion about putting it in `/etc/profile.d` where it will be automatically sourced on new shell instances ;
3. As @wich is suggesting, there's no reason to add an alias for `killprocessatport` to `fuserfunction`. Though, you may prefer to do an alias for a call to the function with a parameter like: `alias killhttpserver=fuserfunction 80`
4. It'd be also a good idea to use an **explicit** name for your `fuserfunction`, something like `fuserkillproc` or even something better you may come up with…

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it won't work when I `sudo` the command. It workks for the user that is not superuser but I want to be able to sudo the command. What can be done?

Comment: root is probably set up with a different shell and/or does not source /etc/profile hence the alias is never defined for root

Comment: @909Niklas, `sudo` can't be used to call functions **or** aliases. If you want to use sudo, you need to make an executable script.

Comment: @909Niklas ...also, if your end goal is to define something you can run under `sudo`, maybe your question should specify that?

Comment: CAUTION: You are trying to open an sudo (i.e. root permission) to user to kill ANY program running on any certain TCP port.  It is dangerous!  You at least need a script to check the port range.

Comment: Check the sudo manual.  It can be configured to run a specific command with specific arguments by specific accounts with a specific permission (i.e. run as if the user has the permission of a certain account).  The specific command includes a script.  Thus you can write a script, to check port range for example, and grant the permission to kill the processes or not...