# Ways to execute bash script without "./"?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script called climb.sh. When I execute it I write

```sh
./climb.sh 1
```

while inside the directory in which the script is located. However, I want to do the same thing wherever I am, and across all shell sessions by simply calling

```sh
climb 1
```

Also, climb.sh takes an numeric argument and calls "cd ../" that many times. In order for the program to work, it has to run alongside the current process, not within some child process.

How to achieve all this?
Thanks

Comment: Don't use file extensions on executables. If you have a valid shebang and an execute bit set on your script, your script is an executable; just as you have `/usr/bin/ls` instead of `/usr/bin/ls.elf`, you should have `/usr/local/bin/climb` instead of `/usr/local/bin/climb.sh`. (`/usr/local/bin` is important because, as described in the linked duplicate, it's a location in the default search `PATH` environment variable used to find executables used without a `/` in their names specifying a specific location).

Comment: Thank you. Btw, there is something in my question that isnt duplicable. I asked the same question you proposed to be a dublicate, but for across ALL sessions. I also asked about how to make the program work in regards that it is calling "cd ../". I found out that I have to call source climb.sh. But how to make source climb default, so i need only to call climb. ty

Comment: That's a different question, and the answer boils down to "you can't" -- at least, not without participation of the users whose accounts are involved. (Such participation might mean, f/e, their shells `source`ing all files in `/etc/profile.d/`, such that you need to put your script defining a function in a similar location -- but you'll need to look at your specific OS; there's nothing in bash itself that allows it; things like `/etc/profile.d` are configuration your OS vendor arranges, not functionality built into the shell).

Comment: I've added a link ("How to enable a system-wide function") that's appropriate to that end of the question; see [the answer by zmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21916043/14122), not the accepted one. (Functions are the more-powerful alternative to aliases; any answer that might guide you to `alias climb='source /usr/local/bin/climb.sh'` could instead by written as `climb() { . /usr/local/bin/climb.sh "$@"; }; export -f climb`, installed in the same ways, but then with an impact not only on the shell it's sourced into but also that shell's children).